# How to implement animation of icon?

Tags: animation, icons

Like [this site](http://www.wolai.com)

Pay attention to your address bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate a favicon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They reference two icon files:

This one is for IE that only understands ICO format.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://img1.wolai.com/img/favicon.ico" />
```

This one is for good browsers. This is an animated GIF.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://img1.wolai.com/img/favicon.gif" type="image/gif" />
```

Comment: "This one is for good browsers".  A little biased are we? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their favicon is an **animated gif**. It didn't seem to be animating in Google Chrome (4.x stream), but it works in Firefox.