# Separate icon for browser tab and 'Add To Desktop'

Tags: html, favicon

I've been doing some research on getting a webapp I am working on to display the proper icon / tiles in the correct situation. We have a version of our logo as an .ICO on transparent that we have been using for the icon shown in the browsers tab. No borders from a background, just the logo against the gray of the tab.
Now we want users to be able to add a home screen link to our app. This link's icon should be the logo against a gray background.

For apple this is easy:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="css/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

plus any additional sizes we want to add. The apple-touch prefix makes having a separate file easy.

However, Android is presenting an issue. Currently Android will accept the apple touch icon, but this listed as depreciated and will not work soon. (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#icon) The meta tag given for adding icons to be used for Android (Chrome is the only concern) is listed as:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon-name-192.png">
<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="icon-name-128.png">
```

This will apparently overwrite the favicon when the browser sees it. Which means that if I give these images the wanted gray background, then the icons in my browser tabs will show the gray square. And if these are on transparent then when I add to desktop on ANdroid I get the icons without the gray square.

Am I missing something? This seems like a pretty common request, and yet I cant find a solution. I tried looking at the meta data for other sites where the favicon appears to be on transparency but the desktop version shows on gray / another color, but I dont see any extra tags, and so I assume they are using the apple touch version, which as stated is apprently still legal as of now.

Whats the accepted way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rel="shortcut icon"` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: This was it, thanks. Using this knowledge I was able to search and find this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952907/favicon-ico-vs-link-rel-shortcut-icon which solved the problem perfectly.