# How to add an icon in the address bar in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am reading the book: *Flask Web Developmen*. Below are the book's codes for adding an icon in the address bar:

```
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" 
type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"
type="image/x-icon">

{% endblock %}
```

My question is: why it needs two links to add one icon.
In HTML, this oneline `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico">` is enough for this task. Doesn't it?

Comment: It is, But the shortcut icon is just there for [(see this SO post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952907/favicon-ico-vs-link-rel-shortcut-icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:
Yes, Yes it is enough.
However shortcut icon is for things like Desktop shortcuts or I think even ios Shortcuts. [See This So Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952907/favicon-ico-vs-link-rel-shortcut-icon)