# Adding icon to title in Django project fails

Tags: html, css

I have added this tag to my head tag in html I can see the image when I have inspected the code but I can't get the icon displayed.

```
<link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image" href = "{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
```

I even tried

```
<link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/png" href = "{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
```

and

```
<link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/x-icon" href = "{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
```

but It's of no use

I have referred this link [add logo meta to html](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/add+logo+meta+to+html)
my code goes as this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image" href = "{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
</head>
```

Comment: 1. Press F12. 2. Look in network to see where the browser tries to find the icon. 3. View-source to see if the rendered HTML looks correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952907/what-is-the-best-practice-for-creating-a-favicon-on-a-web-site

Comment: Andchange to `type="image/png"` if indeed it is a png

Comment: I have tried all you mentioned but it didn't work. @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine. You just need to clear cache/cookies for your localhost.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31503433)