# Animated Shortcut Icons

Tags: javascript, html, animation, icons

I was just creating an shortcut icon (the icon displayed in the `head` part of a page before the page title) (EDIT: I mean favicon...) for a webside, when I was thinking about animated shortcut icons (acually I don't know if they are called like that...).

Even though my intuition told me that this is probably impossible, since I haven't seen it being done on any web pages so far, I wanna be sure :^)

I have actually thought about a things that might in theory help to find out if, or how it's possible:

- **Using a gif file**

There might be a way to make it work using a gif, but probably not. That's too easy. It would be widely-used...

- **Changing the icon tag using js for every frame of the icon animation**

This would actually be my best guess, but I can't get it to work...

- **Changing the icon image on the server 10 times per second**

Forget about this one.

- **Find out how the loding icon animation is done**

Well, it's probably browser side and hasn't todo anything with html/js, but who knows?!

So, that's everything I could think of concerning shortcut icon animations, hopefully you can make sense of it :)

Comment: This icon is actually called [`favicon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll change that in the question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate a favicon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon)

Comment: Found this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon 2009, says firefox only. Within that, this answer has a JS version and is from 2016. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489898/3136874

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't knowing that it's called favicon, and therefor I didn't find the question :)