# How do I make an animated (fav)icon?

Tags: html, web, icons, favicon

I'm learning HTML to prepare for my software/game development study, and for that I'm trying to build my own site as a project. I want to make the icon in the top of the tab animated, so I made a .gif of it, and added the following line to my `<head></head>`: `<link rel="icon" href="icon.gif" type="image/gif">`, which I found online. I have the `icon.gif` saved in the same directory as the `.html` file.

I've also tried converting it to an icon, but with no success. Can anyone tell me how I *can* make my tab icon animated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: animated favicon tag only works on firefox, others browsers you have to use JavaScript, checkout this for more solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason this is not working is because the gif size is too large to be favicon.

Try defining the gif size as 50px on 50px or 20px on 20px.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon) might be useful for you aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the answers in the question you shared, but they didn't work for me. It's currently sized at 64x64px so I'll try scaling it down!

Comment: @pinkflameinthepan if that doesn't work, make sure the image isn't damaged, and compatible with the browser.

Comment: I reduced the image size to 20x20px, with no succes. I then checked if it's damaged or not, but it works fine anywhere else- I have no idea if Edge supports animated favicons and I can't find anything on it, would you happen to know?

Comment: @pinkflameinthepan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon