# How to animate a favicon with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, gif, favicon

I want my page's favicon to be an animated gif but i cant get things to work, So I would like to try with javascript but I have no idea what to do

i tried `<link rel="icon" href="bc37a6e9.gif" type="image/gif" /> </head>`
but since i only have chrome it wont show the gif, so how could i use javascript to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate a favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all browsers support this. You can extract your gif frame by frame and then programatically update the favicon src. It's tedious, but really the only way to achieve it in all browsers.

```
const favicon = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
favicon.href="link_to_favicon_frame_1.gif"
// and then do the same in intervals for link_to_favicon_frame_2.gif, link_to_favicon_frame_3.gif, etc.
```

You can also draw to a canvas and use cavas.toDataURL to get a url you can use as your favicon href.

Comment: btw if you answer a question that is a duplicate you risk getting downvoted (I didn't downvote)

Comment: so like this? **view-source:https://anewchanceanewday.neocities.org/gir**